# Spring Security Custom Logout Filter

Tags: spring-security

I created a custom security filter that handles `LOGOUT_FILTER`. Debugging my app, it does reach to `@Override public void onLogoutSuccess`.
I need to be redirected to a different domain/context/url outside my app. However, `response.sendRedirect` doesnt redirect at all to that url.

In Spring Security 3.1 book from RWinch, apparently you can do this, here's the snippet:

```
<http ...>
...
<logout logout-url="/logout" 
    logout-success-url="https://${cas.server.host}/cas/logout"/>
</http>
```

CAS Server is in another context/domain which is different from context app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LogoutSuccessHandler` :

```
pHttp.logout()
        .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest pRequest,
                    HttpServletResponse pResponse,
                    Authentication pAuthentication) throws IOException,
                    ServletException {
                pResponse.sendRedirect("https://${cas.server.host}/cas/logout");
            }
        });
```

I let you translate it in XML config ;)